# React Redux Router rendering nothing in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

This is bugging me so much I had to ask my first question on SO. I'm building a React app with Redux and I'm trying to incorporate React Router. In development it works as expected but once I build it, nothing renders inside the root `div` in the browser. This problem started only after I added Router. Previous dist versions worked just fine.

Here's the code:

index.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import Root from "./Root"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import store from "./store/store"

ReactDOM.render(
        <Root store={store} />,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Root.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Route path="/"  component={App}/>  
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)

export default Root;
```

App.js

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader";
import * as React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actions from './actions/actions';
import  {windowResize} from './actions/windowResize';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Switch,
    Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

import HomePage from './views/HomePage';
import ComparePage from './views/ComparePage';
import CartPage from './views/CartPage';
import ProductPage from './views/ProductPage';
import WishlistPage from './views/WishlistPage';

import "./styles/theme.sass";


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        resize: windowResize
    }, dispatch);
}

class App extends React.Component {
    // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            width: window.innerHeight,
            height: window.innerWidth
        }

        this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
    }

    updateDimensions() {
        let w = window,
            d = document,
            documentElement = d.documentElement,
            body = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            width = w.innerWidth || documentElement.clientWidth || body.clientWidth,
            height = w.innerHeight || documentElement.clientHeight || body.clientHeight;

        this.setState({ width: width, height: height });
        this.props.resize([width, height]);
    }

    //lifecycle methods
    componentWillMount() {
        this.updateDimensions();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
    }
    // - - render - -
    render() {

    return (

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/product" component={ProductPage} />
                <Route path="/compare" component={ComparePage} />
                <Route path="/wishlist" component={WishlistPage} />
                <Route path="/cart" component={CartPage} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            </Switch>

        )
    }

}

export default hot(module)(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App))
```

I'm pasting the whole code as It's possible I'm doing something really dumb and can't see it. I seem to have tried everything I could think of including using `withRouter`. In case there are some conflicts I don't know about, here's the relevant part of my `package.json`

```
"react": "^16.3.0",
"react-dom": "^16.3.0",
"react-hot-loader": "^4.0.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
```

I'm out of ideas of what may be causing the issue. There's something about router or Redux basics that I didn't fully grasp. Will appreciate some help.

Comment: In file `Root.js`, can you try replacing `<Route path="/"  component={App}/>` with `<App />`

Comment: I just did that and it changed nothing at all. The app's still working in dev but not after running build scripts. Also no errors are displayed, it just fails silently.

Comment: thanks for the update, I am not sure, what the problem is, but I noticed another thing, you should not `setState` in `componentWillMount`, you can call your function `this.updateDimensions();` in either constructor and initiate state(not using `setState` but `this.state = ...`) at the start or in `componentDidMount`.

Comment: can you also, try adding a new route, something like this. `<Route path="*" component={FourOFour}></Route>`. It may be the case, that no route is matching, it may give you some insight in the actual problem.

Comment: How are you serving your app after build?

Comment: It sort of helped. I added the line `<Route path="*" component={HomePage} />` . The problem is now that `path="*"` is always a match and no other routing works. URL stays always the same and only `HomePage` is rendered. Thanks for pointing out the `componentWillMount` issue though.   

@Murli so far I've only been running it locally and through github pages

Comment: this might help:https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765

Comment: you have to add this line in the end after all the routes. So that if no any given route matches, this will be the fallback, rather than a blank page. `<Route path="*" component={HomePage} />`

Comment: as @MurliPrajapati, pointed out, are you production testing on url something like `https://{username}.github.io/{repo-name}/`?

Comment: @RaghavGarg Yes, so far I'm only using github for production testing, so the URL looks this way. Also the `path="*"` route is last in my `Switch` component and the app still acts like all the routing is turned off. Although in dev the URL is changing as expected.

Comment: So, it is exactly the issue, @MurliPrajapati, mentioned. Please try adding `basename` prop on `BrowserRouter` and give it the value `/` for development and `repo-name` for production. reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-327615099

Comment: ok, so what I've done is I added `basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` to `BrowserRouter` in `Root.js`. In development it still works only for URLs and doesn't change components visible on page. When I change the URL in browser address bar, say by typing in `/product` and hit `Enter`, the correct component renders. It's like there's a problem with `Link` components (?). In production nothing has changed, only `HomePage` is always rendered. I'm stuck but thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after digging through some forum threads and reading links provided by @MurliPrajapati and @RaghavGarg I think I managed to fix the issue. As suggested, the fix was to provide the prop `basename` to `BrowserRouter`. So in `App.js` changed `render` method looks like this now:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <Router basename={"my-repo-name"} >
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={"/product"} component={ProductPage} />
                    <Route path={"/compare"} component={ComparePage} />
                    <Route path={"/wishlist"} component={WishlistPage} />
                    <Route path={"/cart"} component={CartPage} />
                    <Route path={"/"} exact component={HomePage} />
                    <Redirect from={"*"} to={"/"} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            )
}
```

Of course, as @MurliPrajapati and @RaghavGarg mentioned, this is for production and deployment to GH Pages. If I was to serve the app from my private domain this wouldn't be necessary.

My additional thought might be that there is no simple way of getting this to work on local machine after the build but it does work when deployed to Github Pages so I guess that's good enough for me.

Also to be on the safe side I wrapped relevant components in `withRouter` function from react-router-dom, I'm not sure that was necessary though.